# schema.org markups for search results pages

Tags: seo, google-search, schema.org

Was wondering if there are some markups in schema.org for a search results page which Google currently honors .. I was trying

ItemList (http://schema.org/ItemList)

and

AggregateOffer (http://schema.org/AggregateOffer),

but none of them seems to be coming up on Google yet (as in they still dont support it or show up that markup on the search page). Are there any other markups I can try ?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Search for a restaurant, place, or product and you'll see microformats that google recognizes and uses to format its search results.  Yelp reviews all also have a price range.  They are used widely.  I am pretty sure they use the Places stuff widely as well, and believe I have seen cases of books having author name and so on displayed.

But...

How they are used, in what cases, for what sites, and for what queries google decides to use this information is entirely up to the search engine.

Within weeks of announcements about microformats for product ratings, sites entirely unrelated to the topic were adding microformats having product rating information, so think of them as a hint that Google (and other SE's) might use in some cases when they are confident that it's accurate and helpful.

It might just take time for Google to trust your site.